# Default value of first dropdown disables second but wrong data send to DB

Tags: database, drop-down-menu, disabled-input

I have two dropdowns sending data to database. Each with values 1,2,3. By default 3 is selected from the first and disables the second one, but wrong data is send to DB(default value of the second dropdown, even disabled). Adding default empty option in second dropdown doesn`t seem so good idea for me. How do you resolve such problem? Thanks!

here is code sample:

```
<select name="first_dropwdown" id="first">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select name="second_dropwdown" id="second">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

$('#first_dropdown').click(function(e){
        if($(this).val() == "3"){
            $("#second_dropdown").prop('disabled',true);
        }
        else $("#second_dropdown").prop('disabled',false);
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wah6jez2/

Comment: Please include the code where you send data to a the server. Do you use form submit or ajax? You should validate user input on the server side anyway before writing it to the database...

Answer (score 0):

Actually I`ll need just to prepend one empty disabled option if value of first is '3' and remove it, if such emty option exists and value of the first dropdown is different drom 3. I wrote two functions, but it`s not the expected result. My idea is the empty option to be prepended anyway, because the default value of first dropdown is '3' and to be removed if value of the 1st is different. No event added because I don`t want to prepend a row any time user clicks on the 3rd value from first  dropdown. Here are the two functions:

```
 $('#first_dropdown').change(function(e){
            if($(this).val() == "3"){
                $("#second_dropdown").prop('disabled',true);
            }
            else $("#second_dropdown").prop('disabled',false);
        });

        $(function()){
            if($("#first_dropdown").val() == "3"){
                $("#second_dropdown").prepend('<option value=0 id= "prepended_option" disabled selected></option>');
            }
            else $("#prepended_option").remove();
        });
```